# Show set is closed

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

"Argue that the function has a maximum and minimum value on:

$f(x,y)=2x+3y^2$ and the set $\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq2,x-2\leq y \leq x  \right \}$"

I use the extreme value theorem to show the function has a min/max in this problem. I showed the function is continous AND the domain, bounded. I do not know how to show that it is closed. I know for a set to be closed it has to contain the limit points of the set. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you give me the definition of limit points? There are various (but equivalent) definitions I can take.

Comment: @HanulJeon Honestly I have only gotten hand-wavy definitions and explanations and that is why I am seeking help. I know that a set $A$ is closed if $\bar{A}=A$ and that it is open if $A$ is equal to the interior of $A$.

Comment: Then what is the definition of $\overline{A}$? Is it defined by sequences over $A$, or neighborhoods?

Comment: I think we defined it as $A \cup \partial A$, Where $\partial A$ is the limit points I think  if I am not messing up translations..

Comment: @HanulJeon or is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: Have to specify this is not a discrete math class. I just have to show this in a simple way for the rest of the problem to be solved, as I stated in the post above.

Comment: A set is closed if its complement is open. The set is the same as $ ([0,2] \times \mathbb{R}) \cap \{(x, y) : x-y\leq 2 \} \cap \{(x, y) :x-y\geq 0\} $. You can take the complement of this set in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ and show its open. Then you have a continuous image of a compact set which is bounded and has a maximum and minimum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's name $A=\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq2,x-2\leq y \leq x  \right \}$.

Take some convergent sequence $\big((x_n,y_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset A$ and let's say $(x_n,y_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}(x,y)$. Then $x_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x$ and $y_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}y$.

For every $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $0\le x_n\le 2$, $x_n-2\le y_n\le x_n$, and taking $n\to\infty$ we get $0\le x\le 2$, $x-2\le y\le x$, so $(x,y)\in A$. We could be done, since $A$ is closed if and only if every convergent sequence in $A$ converges to a point in $A$, which we just showed.

However your definition is: $A$ is closed if $\bar A=A$, and $\bar A=A\cup\partial A$. I hope your definition of $\partial A$ is the set of those points that are limit of a nonconstant  sequence in $A$. In that case we are done too, since every nonconstant sequence in $A$ that is convergent is a convergent sequence in $A$ too, and we showed those limits stay in $A$, so $\partial A$ stays contained in $A$, i.e., $\partial A\subseteq A$. Therefore $A\cup\partial A\subseteq A\cup A=A\subseteq A\cup\partial A\Rightarrow \bar A=A\cup\partial A=A$, so $A$ is closed.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but there is 1 part I am not understanding, " In that case we are done too, since every nonconstant sequence in $A$ that is convergent is a convergent sequence in $A$ too". Are these 2 statements in the sentence not the same?

Comment: Not exactly. I proved that every convergent sequence in $A$ has its limit in $A$. The sentence talking about $\partial A\subseteq A$ is that every **nonconstant** convergent sequence in $A$ has its limit in $A$, which is a weaker statement, since every **nonconstant** convergent sequence is a convergent sequence.

Comment: I think I am getting the gist but it is still a bit unclear to me. I.e I am trying for a bit different problem seen in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886071/show-that-the-domain-is-closed. I think it is the same method but when $y$ is not dependent on $x$ I am not sure on how to write it up..