# Show that the domain is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to show that the domain defined by the half unit circle: $\left \{ \left ( x,y \right )\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1, x\geq 0 \right \}$

for the function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is closed (the function is $f(x,y)=2xy^2-2x^2$), so that I can argue the function has a min/max value. I have shown it is bounded and continuous.

Comment: Perhaps you can write your set as an intersection of two closed (but simpler) sets. For example preimages of $(-\infty,1]$ and $[0,\infty)$ over appropriate continuous functions?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is what you are asking; but $x$ would have to be in the interval $[0,1)$, right?

Comment: @freakish I am lost I think...

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $g(x, y)=x$. Both are continuous. Then your set is equal to $f^{-1}((-\infty, 1])\cap g^{-1}([0,\infty))$ which is closed as an intersection of closed sets.

Comment: But how would you show it is closed, simple set or not - how would one “formally” show it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** You can write$$\left \{ \left ( x,y \right )\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1, x\geq 0 \right \} = g^{-1}([0,1]\times [0, +\infty))$$

where $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2$ is the *continuous* function defined for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$g(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x)$$

Comment: I think I see the idea but I would guess it is not what is intended for this problem given  to me.

Comment: Can this be done in a more standard way?

Comment: @mathstudent23 I guess, but proving that it is the preimage of a closed set by a continous functions is a very standard (maybe the most standard !) way to show that something is closed !

Comment: But how would you show it is closed, simple set or not - how would one “formally” show it.

Comment: @mathstudent23 I don't understand your question. My answer *shows* that the set is closed, the argument is formal enough. If the question asks to use a specific argument, then you should precise it : I cannot guess which argument is allowed and which is not !