# Method/approach to show given set is closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to show that the domain defined by the half unit circle: $\left \{ \left ( x,y \right )\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1, x\geq 0 \right \}$

for the function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is closed (the function is $f(x,y)=2xy^2-2x^2$), so that I can argue the function has a min/max value. I have shown it is bounded and continuous. I just can not seem to find a method or way to “formally” show it is closed? I get the intersection of 2 closed sets is closed but how would one ACTUALLY show these sets are closed?

Comment: I am aware that this is your own question. Indeed this is why I am voting to close. The answer you received there is perfectly satisfactory.

Comment: Maybe try showing that the complement of the set is open... It might be easier for you to work with open sets.

Comment: @Tyrone No, I am asking how the 2 sets are closed which is just assumed (probably because it is obvious and not too difficult to show) but it was not shown. I am asking exactly how one would show that the 2 sets Are closed and then the intersection argument follows. I am interested in an approach/method for the first part. So yes it is a correct answer but does not help me understand/improve.

Comment: Do you want to show that $D=\{(x,y); x^2 +y^2 \leq 1\} \cap \{(x,y); x \geq 0\}$ is closed using that each factor is closed or do you want see why $[0,1] \times [0, +\infty)$ is closed in order to fully understand the answer given in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886071/show-that-the-domain-is-closed?

Comment: @PAM1499 I want to show that each set is closed since I know the intersection of closed setsm is closed. The problem is I have gotten the argument because it is greater/less than or equal signs on $x$ and $y$ but that does not explain it to me.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Ok. I tried to show it by showing that the complement is open... You might take a look. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PAM1499 I did not know this method was possible so thanks a lot! But choosing $\delta$ is a bit of a mystery to me. Why did you arrive at that result? And then I have to find a radius for the ball for $A^c$ as well but still - the $\delta$ part is throwing me off

Comment: Think about it... You are in the half plane and all that really matters is the distance you are from the x axis. So you choose an $\delta$ such that it is less then this distance in a way your open ball stays in the half plane. Edit: for the other set this choice is "trickier". If you can't see try a sketch. It really can help

Comment: Sketch would just be all of the plane just excluding the unit circle, right? But the thing that is throwing me off is what the ball HAS to do for it to show a property? i.e I know to show a domain is bounded I have to make a ball that has a radius big enough to contain the domain. I do not know that you could do a some-what similar (I guess) approach to show a set is closed.

Comment: Okay I just got the definition and why the ball works here. Now I just need an $\delta$ for $A^c$

Comment: Oh, ok. Then try to think about how to take this $\delta$. Think about the distance of a point in $A^c$ to the origin.

Comment: It has to be greater than 1 for it to be outside the unit circle but the fact that it is not a number i.e as to prove set is bounded is throwing me off. Would $\delta = \left |x^2+y^2+1   \right |$ be sufficient?

Comment: Actually not... Think about it, given a point $p \in A^c$. Take $\delta =\frac{d(p,0) -1}{2}$. Where $d(p,0)$ is the distance between $0$ and $p$

Comment: You can even take $\delta = d(p,0)-1$ and your ball will be "touching" the unit circle...

Comment: You might take a look at it (hope the link works)... Given the blue dot we are choosing that green ball. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tmy3a5uout

Comment: Okay so it is basically the opposite of what I said. But still, the fact that $\delta$ contains a variable and not a number is throwing me off. It kind of makes sense for $B^c$ but for $A^c$ where we are dealing with multivariables I do not know what to do.

Comment: You mean because the $\delta$ depends of the point $p$ we are given?

Comment: Wouldn't we be able to pick any delta that just holds the fact that it is just touching the unit circle i.e not containing any of the boundry points?

Comment: Well... you can allways choose such $\delta$ to be as I said $\delta=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1$. But notice that the dependence on the point comes with the definition of being open. A set is not open if there is $\delta$ such every ball of radius $\delta$ is in A. A is open if, given a point $a \in A$, we can find $\delta(a)$ such that the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $a$ is in A

Comment: @PAM1499 at this point I think it might be easier to say that they are obviously closed as the boundry points of $A$ and $B$ are in the sets because of the greater/lesser than or equal symbols... I want to do the formal way but there is simply too many balls at this point.

Comment: Oh, for sure there are easier ways of proving it. Since I didn't know what you can or can not use I tried to do It by definition. I just hope it helped a little bit

Comment: Yes it sure did. I did not even know that the definition was as such. What simple way is there if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Well, one easy way was the one presented to you as the pre image of a continuous function. Which actually is a simple result of continuity.

Comment: Just to clarify I used the definition of open sets. You could also try to prove it using the definition of closed sets.

Comment: @PAM1499 yes I understand the part regarding showing the compliment is open. In the other post are you refering to the comment by freakish?

Comment: Yes and even the answer given. But the comment  prove it for the sets A and B so I think it is easier to understand

Comment: @PAM1499 Okay the only thing I found odd was this "[...] which is closed as an intersection of closed sets". Why is this a given? Is it just that obvious that both sets $A$ and $B$ are closed because of the $<$ and $=$ symbol?

Comment: Ohh no... He is not talking about it. The point is that the pre image of closed set is a closed set. But $(-\infty, 1], [0,\infty)$ are closed (agree?). So A and B as continuous pre images of these closed sets are closed

Comment: Is there a synonym to the pre image? Is it just the inverse?

Comment: Given a function $f:X\to Y$ the pre image is defined for $A \subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(A)=\{x \in X ; f(x) \in A\}$. And no, it is not the inverse. It is just the notation used.

Answer (score 0):

Notice $D=A \cap B$ where $A=\{(x,y); x^2 +y^2 \leq 1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y); x \geq 0\}$. Let's show that $B^c=\{(x,y); x < 0\}$ and $A^c=\{(x,y); x^2 +y^2 > 1\}$ are open. Notice that given $(x,y) \in B^c$ we know that $x<0$. By choosing $\delta = \frac{|x|}{2}$ we get
$$
B((x,y),\delta) \subset B^c
$$
where $B((x,y),\delta)$ is the ball centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $\delta$. So we can conclude that $B^c$ is open. Hence $B$ is closed. Try to do something similar with $A^c$. Then you will have that $D$ is the intersection of closed sets as you want.